# to read .csv files in R

Tags: r, csv

I need some help. I'm begginer on R and I don't know how to read .csv files from different folders. I only know how to read  files from one folder. One folder is with new data .csv and other with old data .csv and i have to read them in two massives. (Note: there are many files in both folders). Later I will have to compare new vs old files. Could you help me to write a code for that? or just tell some advices. Thank u.

Comment: What is a massive?  You should start by searching Google and Stack Overflow for `read.csv/read.table`.

Comment: If you know how to read a file in one folder then you know how to read a file in any folder. I don't see what the issue is. If you want help, it would help if you give a [mcve]. As it is, this is much too broad since you are essentially  asking about how to process files in R.

Comment: What are your two paths? You need to know them. Asking us isn't going to tell you that. Use Windows file explorer or search or whatever to locate the files' paths.

Answer (score 3):

Without a minimal example, I can only show you general solution.

You can list all files in a directory using `list.files`. Next, you iterate over them and read each file into a list.

```
old_path <- 'your/path/to/old/folder/'
files_old <- list.files(path = old_path, pattern = '.csv')
read_files_old <- list()
for(f in files_old){ 
   read_files_old[[f]] <-read.csv(paste0(old_path ,f)) 
}
```

Next, you do the same for the new files:

```
new_path <- 'your/path/to/new/folder/'
files_new <- list.files(path = new_path, pattern = '.csv')
read_files_new <- list()
for(f in files_new){ #
  read_files_new[[f]] <-read.csv(paste0(new_path,f)) 
}
```

Later, you can compare them in any way you like.

If you do not want to you use a for loop, you can use lapply like this:

```
read_files_old <- lapply(files_old, read.csv)
```

Comment: thanks.  But when i use your code, R says 'Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'G5N00131(1).csv': No such file or directory'

Comment: @EglėPugačiova I updated my answer. Now you should not get an error in the for loops